# Extjs 4.2 TreeGrid collapse/expand node does not remove preceding node

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a treegrid in extjs 4.2. I load some data. let's say 1 node with some children. I expand the node, the children are there. I collapse the node and expand it again. After the second expand, the children are duplicated. And so and so on, after each expand, children are always duplicated.

Did anyone else encounter this situation?

```
store.setRootNode(firstLevelNodesList);
store.getRootNode().appendChild(firstLevelNodesList);
store.getRootNode().expandChildren();
```

firstLevelNodesList is a list of nodes (they are built correctly). the call is made on first opening a window with the grid in it. The stragen behaviour is when I click on collapse/expand

Comment: how are you adding the children? If you are creating and rendering a component into the new node, you may have to check if that node is empty

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

All configuration should be done in `Store`.

In your example:

```
store.setRootNode(firstLevelNodesList);
store.getRootNode().appendChild(firstLevelNodesList);
store.getRootNode().expandChildren();
```

You are getting root node and appending another children after you collapse and expand tree. Over and over again.

This how my tree configuration works:

`Store` configuration

```
Ext.define('Items', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    storeId : 'Items',
    model   : 'Item',
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: false,
    root: {
        expanded: false,
        text: 'items'//recurence data trough tree object for expanding. Check your json data. Can be different.
    },
    proxy:proxy//proxy definition
});
```

And only one thing i do is (Example):

```
        var treeUserStore = controller.getStore('Items');
        treeUserStore.load({
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                var userPanel = controller.getUserManagementPanel();//some grid panel
           userPanel.getRootNode().expand();//example.
            }});
```